# How do I quickly find out whether two (large) factors are relabelings of each other?

Tags: r, r-factor

I have two vectors of factors and suspect that they carry the same information up to relabeling. How can I find out whether this is correct?

My problem is that both vectors are pretty long (200,000 entries), with a large number of levels (4,000). Some levels are very frequent, but there is a "long tail" of levels that only occur once each.

Here is a reproducible example (sorry, I couldn't find a way to compactify it and still show the properties of my data):

```
foo <- structure(c(3213L, 428L, 104L, 59L, 23L, 17L, 15L, 9L, 5L, 6L, 
1L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Dim = 69L, .Dimnames = structure(list(
    c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", 
    "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "23", "33", "83", "205", "246", 
    "255", "319", "374", "379", "389", "552", "566", "595", "686", 
    "750", "846", "965", "999", "1006", "1254", "1514", "1535", 
    "1605", "1687", "1744", "1792", "1937", "1946", "2166", "2198", 
    "2206", "2420", "2503", "2736", "2965", "2986", "3036", "3273", 
    "3734", "4026", "4073", "4279", "5038", "5040", "5185", "5607", 
    "6298", "6609", "6930", "15392", "21083", "22933", "29357"
    )), .Names = ""), class = "table")
bar <- as.numeric(rep(names(foo),times=foo))
factor.1 <- as.factor(rep(paste0("a",sprintf("%04i",1:length(bar))),times=bar))
set.seed(1)
factor.2 <- as.factor(sample(gsub("a","b",unique(factor.1)),length(unique(factor.1)))[
  as.numeric(factor.1)])
```

After this exercise, `factor.1` and `factor.2` are simply relabelings of each other. So, how can we find out whether this holds for new vectors?

Things that *don't* work:

1. The internal integer coding does not need to be the same, so simply checking whether `cor(as.numeric(factor.1),as.numeric(factor.2))==1` will not work.
2. I tried checking whether to each factor level of `factor.1` there corresponds exactly one factor level of `factor.2` and vice versa. Unfortunately, this takes way too long, on the order of hours:

   ```
   foo <- by(factor.1,factor.2,FUN=function(zz)length(unique(zz)))
   bar <- by(factor.2,factor.1,FUN=function(zz)length(unique(zz)))
   all(foo) & all(bar)
   ```
3. If we can perfectly fit `factor.1` in a multinomial model using `factor.2` as a predictor and vice versa, both carry the same information. Unfortunately, `nnet::multinom(factor.1~factor.2)` yields the dreaded "cannot allocate a vector of size XX" error. `randomForest::randomForest()`, which would at least give us a probabilistic answer, cannot handle factors with more than 53 levels.
4. We could run `table(factor.1,factor.2)` and check whether every row has exactly one non-zero entry. Which again runs out of memory.

Comment: I guess a simple way would be `length(unique(paste0(factor.1, factor.2))) == length(unique(factor.1))`.  But not particularly efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first function counts the number of unique elements of its argument and the second returns TRUE if there is one level of x for every level of y.  If that is so for factor.1 and factor.2 and if they use the same number of levels one is a relabeling of the other.  With the given data it returns immediately so it seems pretty fast.  The last line is a faster version of one of your ideas.  Use either one.

```
cnt <- function(x) length(unique(x))
all_one <- function(x, y) all(tapply(unclass(x), y, cnt) == 1)

# solution 1
all_one(factor.1, factor.2) && cnt(factor.1) == cnt(factor.2)

# solution 2
all_one(factor.1, factor.2) && all_one(factor.2, factor.1)
```